# Delete a period and a number at the end of a character string

Tags: regex, r

How do I delete a trailing period (`.`) followed by a number (one or two digits in length) directly preceding it?  Example:

```
z <- c("awe", "p.56.red.45", "ted.5", "you.88.tom")
```

I only want to remove the `.45` and the `.5`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You just need a simple regular expression:

```
z_new = gsub("\\.[0-9]*$", "", z)
```

A few comments:

1. The first argument in gsub is the pattern we are looking for. The second argument is what to replace it with (in this case, nothing).
2. The `$` character looks for the pattern at the end of the string
3. `[0-9]*` looks for 1 or more digits. Alternatively, you could use `\\d*` or `[[:digit:]]*`.
4. `\\.` matches the full stop. We need to escape the full stop with two slashes.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
gsub("\\.[[:digit:]]*$", "", z)
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is with a regular expression replacement statement. How you do this depends on the language that you are using.

Here's the regex pattern you need to identify the trailing numbers

> (.\d{1,2})^

And you should simply replace the matches with `""`